# Subset a Column of a dataframe stored as a reactive expression eventReactive

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

Forgive the non-reproducible example. A theoretical solution will do just fine. I want to know **how to subset a dataframe stored in a reactive expression for one particular column, to be be assigned a unique output_id, and ultimately displayed in the UI**. This is analogous to accessing a column of a dataframe like so: `df$column_name`

---

I store a dataframe as a reactive expression called `data()`, using `eventReactive()` which is linked with an `actionButton()` in the UI.

**Code in Environment:**

```
# dataframe with n columns and k rows
df
```

**UI:**

```
actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Update")
```

**SERVER:**

```
# create a reactive expression 'data()', a subsetted data.frame based on other reactive values

data() <- eventReactive( input$go, { df %>% filter(based on other reactive values) } )

output$output_id <- renderSomething( { code depends on data()$specific column })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the following example answers what you are after. The UI has a multi select list, the entries of the lists can be used to subset the `Species` column of `iris` data set.

```
# Using multi select list to sum columns
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Subset and sum a column of iris"),
   fluidRow(
     selectInput('Species', 'Species', levels(iris$Species), multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE)
   ),
   fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput('selection')),
  fluidRow(tableOutput('dataColumn')),
  fluidRow(
    tags$h2("sum:"),
    verbatimTextOutput('sum')
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$selection <- reactive(input$Species)
  subiris = reactive({
    subset(iris, Species %in% input$Species)
  })
  output$dataColumn <- renderTable(subiris()$Sepal.Length)
 output$sum <- renderPrint(sum(subiris()$Sepal.Length)) 
} 


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this is not exactly what I'm asking. In your example, in `output$subdata <- renderTable(data())`, I don't want to call **all** of the filtered data. I want only **one column** of the filtered data, something like `data()$SepalLength`. I need to know how to subset `data()` for **only that one column**.

Comment: I have updated the solution, hope this works for you.

Comment: Excellent. It's really just as simple as using a $ then?