# Trying to reconcile logging verse textOutput in R Shiny reactive values

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

When building out a shiny application and testing management of reactive components I came across this oddity when trying to dynamically fill textOutputs based on a selection in another table.  I am unable to show the correct value in the textOutput but the Shiny Logger would seem to indicate my value is correct.

UI ouput is the row number.

Shinylogger output is the accountID

POC developed from these resources:

[Subset a Column of a dataframe stored as a reactive expression eventReactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150358/subset-a-column-of-a-dataframe-stored-as-a-reactive-expression-eventreactive)

[Returning a dataframe in a reactive function in R Shiny Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876948/returning-a-dataframe-in-a-reactive-function-in-r-shiny-dashboard)

POC code below.

Looking to reconcile why the shinylogger value is different from the textOutput value in the UI.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyEventLogger)
library(bs4Dash)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(

fluidRow(
    column(
        width = 12,
        div(
            bs4Dash::bs4Card(
                id = "searchtableCard",
                title = "Search Results",
                elevation = 3,
                width = 12,
                closable = FALSE,
                DT::dataTableOutput("searchTable")
            )
        )
    )
),
fluidRow(
    textOutput("accountid")
)
)

server <- function(input, output){
shinyEventLogger::set_logging(
    r_console = TRUE, 
    file = TRUE,
    js_console = TRUE)
shinyEventLogger::set_logging_session()

searchresults <- data.frame(
    accountID = c("12345", "54321"),
    lastname = c("McDingus", "McKraken"),
    phone1 = c("555-123-5432", "555-000-5432")
)

applications <- data.frame(
    accountID = c("12345", "54321"),
    firstname = c("Alison", "Angus"),
    lastname = c("McDingus", "McKraken"),
    veh_make = c("Dodge", "Honda"),
    veh_model = c("Charger", "Civic")
)

searchreactive <- shiny::reactive({searchresults})


# Search Table Output
output$searchTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    searchreactive()
},
extensions = "Responsive", filter = "bottom", selection = 'single'
)

shiny::observeEvent(input$searchTable_rows_selected, {
    
    s = input$searchTable_rows_selected
    selRow <- searchreactive()[s,]
    id = selRow[[1]]
    
    
    app_active <- applications %>%
        filter(accountID == id)
    
    shinyEventLogger::log_value(app_active$accountID)
    output$accountid <- shiny::renderText(app_active$accountID)
    
})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: not sure why it would need to be a uiOutput for the sake of this question.  Tested, this did not change the output value.

Attempted the brackets in the renderText, this also did not change the value.  The app still displays the correct value in the logger and the row number in the UI output.

Comment: Can you provide the steps/clicks one has to do in the app to see this behaviour? For me it seems fine, when I click on a row I see the corresponding accountid in the textOutput

Comment: Sure thing.  Load code into R studio, run app.  When the app comes up, click on a row.  You should see in your console window that the accountID value, either 12345 or 54321 is displayed in the R studio command console.  In the UI however, under the table you will see a 1 or a 2 displayed, indicating the row number and not the value in the accountID.